# Steam login realm and return do not match

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

```
openid.mode=error&openid.error=realm+and+return_to+do+not+match
```

I get this error sometimes when trying to use steam openid, but when it happens if i try to log in again it then works fine and will do in-till I restart the browser. I've tried forcing it to be the same on realm and return but it still happens.

```
        public function SteamGenUrl($returnTo = false, $useAmp = FALSE)
        {
            //$returnTo = (!$returnTo) ? (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://www.siteurl.com/login/steam' : '';

            $returnTo = "http://www.siteurl.com/login/steam";

            $params = array(
                'openid.ns'         => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
                'openid.mode'       => 'checkid_setup',
                'openid.return_to'  => $returnTo,
                //'openid.realm'        => (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                'openid.realm'      => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                'openid.identity'   => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
                'openid.claimed_id' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',

            );

            $sep = ($useAmp) ? '&amp;' : '&';
            return self::STEAM_LOGIN . '?' . http_build_query($params, '', $sep);
        }
```

You get sent to /login/steam first where this happens:

```
if(empty($_GET)){
    header('Location: '.$this->Login_model->SteamGenUrl());
}
```